# SharePoint 2010 Site Collection Access

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-enterprise

I have a minor problem which nevertheless requires some smarts to approach in a time efficient manner. In a given SharePoint 2010 Farm one power user has created a number of site collections (>50) containing important information. No one else has access. I need to go through and:

1. Identify which site collections this power user owns.
2. Assign ownership or full control to another existing user.

Is there a quick way to do this or is it just going to be through hard slog?

Answer (score 1):

You could use Powershell to do that. A quick search revealed this, found [here](http://saltypc.com/?p=478):

```
# This script will add a named Site Collection Administrator
# to all Site Collections within a Web Application.
#
######################## Start Variables ########################
$newSiteCollectionAdminLoginName = "domain\user"
$newSiteCollectionAdminEmail = "email@saltypc.com"
$newSiteCollectionAdminName = "Eric Kirkpatrick"
$newSiteCollectionAdminNotes = ""
$siteURL = "https://yourwebapplication" #Web Application URL
$add = 1 # 1 for adding this user, 0 to remove this user
######################## End Variables ########################
Clear-Host
$siteCount = 0
[system.reflection.assembly]::loadwithpartialname("Microsoft.SharePoint")
$site = new-object microsoft.sharepoint.spsite($siteURL)
$webApp = $site.webapplication
$allSites = $webApp.sites
######################## Write Progress Declaration ######################## 
$i = 0
foreach ($site in $allSites)
{
    $web = $site.openweb()
    $web.allusers.add($newSiteCollectionAdminLoginName, $newSiteCollectionAdminEmail, $newSiteCollectionAdminName, $newSiteCollectionAdminNotes)

    $user = $web.allUsers[$newSiteCollectionAdminLoginName]
    $user.IsSiteAdmin = $add
    $user.Update()
    $web.Dispose()
    $siteCount++

######################## Update Counter and Write Progress ########################
   $i++
   Write-Progress -Activity "Adding $newSiteCollectionAdminName to all site collections within $siteURL.  Please wait..." -status "Added: $i of $($allSites.Count)" -percentComplete (($i / $allSites.Count)  * 100)
}
$site.dispose()
write-host "Updated" $siteCount "Site Collections."
```